# Can I start multiple Docker containers based on same image at the same time?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, containers

I have already setup a few containers based on one image but every time I boot the hosts (in Ubuntu primarily) I have to restart multiple docker container manually but the majority has the same image.

I know I can do it with some kind of customisation to the boot command but I am curious whether I can directly just have the command start containers that are based on selected images since each of these containers have different names.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--restart=always` on `docker run`.

More details in:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart